# Self hosted SignalR with MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to use a self hosted signalR server with an MVC(4) application such that it is totally seperate from the signalR server?

I tried Tim and Patrick's beautifully executed [SignalR intro tutorial](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20-and-mvc-5), and was wondering if I could try that? And even if I could, would that offer any performance advantages over an integrated service as is metioned in the tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is absolutely possible to self-host a SignalR 2.0 server with OWIN and accessing this server from within any Website (which may be a MVC application). The only thing you need is to enable CORS (app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll); in your Startup file of the Owin Host) since it's not on the same domain as your Website. Obviously you can't use SignalR within the MVC application itself this way (e.g. to publish messages).

I'm using a self-hosted ASP.NET Web API 2 and SignalR 2 server with OWIN to serve data to clients. You can find an example server using this scenario [here](https://github.com/timbussmann/Battleships). Tho advantage in this approach is to have your views & styles sepparated from your data and business logic. Making everything very easy to cache and scale.

Comment: Actually, I've already tried to implement it, by enabling all CorsOptions in the self hosted SignalR server, but, it seems to be not working. My javascript wont execute beyond setting the hubs URL for the connection. Anyway, glad to know I'm not trying something out which maybe impossible.

Comment: How did you configure the hub on the client? What kind oferrors did you get? Did you try something like this:
`$.connection.hub.url = 'http://<your-host>/signalr';
            var hub = $.connection.<yourHub>;
            hub.client.<yourClientFunction> = function () {
                // do stuff here
            };

            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                console.log('established hub connection')
            });`

Comment: Yup, thats exactly how I tried it out. But, I've got it. Wrapping my scripts with @section scripts{} magically made them work. Im actually new to MVC4 and I have no idea why the normal method didnt work.

Comment: Probably a problem with the order which the scripts got loaded? jQuery needs to be loaded before the signalR library. Without the script section, your code probably got loaded before jQuery. Glad it worked out.